# Query SharePoint listdata.svc with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm running SharePoint 2010 and I have a requirement to be able to query SharePoint from Powershell without having the SharePoint snap-in.  I have been experimenting with some code that I found but I'm having trouble filtering the list items. The script below always displays all the items in the output when I'm expecting one item. What's the best way to filter list items?

```
$url = "https://mysite/market/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?$filter=Title eq 'Movies'"

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url) 
$request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true 
$request.Accept = ‘application/json;odata=verbose’

$response = $request.GetResponse() 
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
# ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot convert the Json string because a dictionary converted from it contains duplicated keys ‘Id’ and ‘ID’. 
$response = $reader.ReadToEnd() 
#$response = $reader.ReadToEnd() -creplace ‘"ID":’, ‘"DummyId":’

$result = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $response 
$result.d.results | select Id, Title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the url as below, add `before $filter:

```
$url = "http://sp10/sites/test/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?`$filter=Title eq 'Movies'"

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url) 
$request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true 
$request.Accept = ‘application/json;odata=verbose’

$response = $request.GetResponse() 
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
# ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot convert the Json string because a dictionary converted from it contains duplicated keys ‘Id’ and ‘ID’. 
$response = $reader.ReadToEnd() 
#$response = $reader.ReadToEnd() -creplace ‘"ID":’, ‘"DummyId":’

$result = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $response 
$result.d.results | select Id, Title
```

This is the test list data:

[image]

This is the filtered result in PowerShell:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jerry!  This works great now.  Is there any reason this same filter wouldn't work with Invoke-RestMethod?  

$ListItem = Invoke-RestMethod "http://sp10/sites/test/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?`$filter=Title eq 'Movies''" -UseDefaultCredentials

$ListItem| ForEach-Object {$_.content.properties}

Comment: See my other related question which is similar but uses Invoke-RestMethod. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271214/invoke-restmethod-with-listdata-svc-help

Comment: @gsr51,you are welcome.  Invole-RestMethod question has been answered.