# Invoke-RestMethod with ListData.svc Help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I'm using SP2010 and trying to understand how to pass a filter to Invoke-RestMethod. I recently learned about adding the ` character before the filter. But the script below doesn't have an error or return anything. If I remove the tick mark before the filter it returns all the items when there should be only one item that matches 'Movies'.

```
$ListItem = Invoke-RestMethod "https://mysite/market/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?`$filter=Title eq 'Movies'"
$ListItem| ForEach-Object {$_.content.properties}
```

How do I make the filter work when using the Invoke-RestMethod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You syntax is correct - but you need to include an Accept header to tell the service if you want the results as XML or JSON. To get XML results use this code:

```
$ListItem = Invoke-RestMethod "https://mysite/market/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?`$filter=Title eq 'Movies'" -Headers @{"Accept"="application/atom+xml" }
$ListItem.Title     # Gets the value of the Title property
```

To get the results as JSON use this:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod "https://mysite/market/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Products?`$filter=Title eq 'Movies'" -Headers @{"Accept"="application/json;odata=verbose" }
$ListItem = $result.d.results
$ListItem.Title     # Gets the value of the Title property
```

Finally, you will of course also need to authenticate with SharePoint. For Windows authentication, simply use the parameter -Credential  or -UseDefaultCredentials

Comment: Thank you Lars.  This is perfect.